# how to set specific scopes for specific client in laravel passport

Tags: laravel, oauth-2.0, laravel-passport

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    $query = http_build_query([
        'client_id' => 3, // Replace with Client ID
        'redirect_uri' => 'http://127.0.0.1:8001/callback',
        'response_type' => 'code',
        'scope' => 'admin user'
    ]);

    return redirect('http://127.0.0.1:8000/oauth/authorize?'.$query);
});
```

I'm new to using Laravel Passport,I want to set dynamically client scope, not declare in scope by hard coded.

Answer (score 0):

Not specific to passport, more Laravel, but you could try this

```
Route::get('/{scope}', function ($scope) {
    $query = http_build_query([
        'client_id' => 3, // Replace with Client ID
        'redirect_uri' => 'http://127.0.0.1:8001/callback',
        'response_type' => 'code',
        'scope' => $scope
    ]);

    return redirect('http://127.0.0.1:8000/oauth/authorize?'.$query);
});
```

[Info here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/routing#required-parameters)